# Save a list of strings to sqlite database in Swift 4

Tags: ios, list, sqlite, swift4

Is it possible to save a list of strings into a SQLite column in swift4?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an array data type like you find in some SQL engines, SQLite does not have that. You theoretically could encode this list somehow (e.g. a JSON array), but that's pretty kludgy. So, I'd probably go ahead and normalize that, putting the multiple strings in a separate table.

E.g. Let's say you wanted a table `users`, that had `user_id`, `name`, and an array of `privileges`. You'd probably instead do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE users_privileges (
    user_privilege_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    privilege TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
```